# Is there an alternative to Dropbox which has an smaller CPU overhead

Tags: macos, dropbox

Ok, this is not necessarily strictly Mac, however it does affect my Macs differently.

I have an 5 years old iMac which is ok with Dropbox running all the time, while my brand new MBP (2017) struggle with Dropbox's CPU overhead (struggles is an exaggeration but it does get the fan running at full blast most of the time). I'm a heavy user and have the higher plan, which means there are some files that are constantly being modified, yet I find it extremely annoying to have it happening.

Is there an alternative which uses less resources?

Comment: Hi, did you check https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/high-cpu-usage ?

Comment: I'm running [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/) on all my devices except Linux and it uses very little CPU.

Comment: I also used a one-TB OneDrive.  I didn't measure CPU, but I was frustrated with it not seeming to work well.  WhenI went to the school's Windows machines, sometimes my file changes were not there.  I finally switched to automounting the Windows disk on my Mac (which had its own set of problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This annoyed me too so I built [Rsync Client](http://bonhardcomputing.com/rsync-client/).  It's like an FTP app but uses rsync, and it only runs when you invoke it, so it's not relentlessly chewing resources. It works with many backend storage service providers, so you control where your data goes.

Comment: Does your tool provide cloud storage as Dropbox does?

Comment: Because any remote host can be used as storage, I might be tempted to recommend something like rsync.net for now.  Or even Dreamhost, Amazon, etc, etc.  Am glad you mentioned that though because it would be easy to provide cloud storage... (although I think I'd rather that people held their data wherever they felt comfortable holding it, rather than entrusting that critical factor to someone else, if you know what I mean).